# Scalability Challenges with Laravel and Redis Queue Worker for Email Verification

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, autoscaling

I have developed an email verification tool using Laravel, hosted on EC2 instances with t3.xlarge, auto scaling, and load balancing. The verification process involves a Redis queue worker and Laravel Horizon for job management.

**Bulk Email Verification Logic:**

1. When a user uploads a list of 10k emails,
2. I dispatch a StartBulkEmailVerificationJob.
3. This job utilizes Laravel's job batching to dispatch
4. VerifyChunkBulkEmailVerificationJob, with each job processing a chunk of 35 emails.
5. For a 10k-email list, this results in 286 VerifyChunkBulkEmailVerificationJob jobs being dispatched.

**Challenge:**

The current setup works smoothly for a single user, but when multiple users simultaneously upload 10k-email lists, subsequent users have to wait for the completion of the previous users' jobs.

**Specific Questions:**

1. Are there any recommended strategies or tools to optimize the parallel processing of bulk email verification jobs for multiple users in a Laravel + EC2 setup?
2. Are there additional features or configurations in Laravel Horizon or Redis queue that I may not be aware of, which could improve parallel processing and reduce waiting times for users?

**Conclusion:**

I'm looking for insights, recommendations, or best practices to enhance the scalability of my email verification tool in a multi-user scenario. Any advice on optimizing the existing setup or introducing new tools/strategies would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: This seems a bit broad a question for SO. But have you tried adding more workers?

Comment: are you using the same provider to send these emails? While you might increase the through put of your jobs you might also reach the api limits of your provider.

Comment: @aynber & krisgjika, Thank you for your comments! 

I searched for a better solution but couldn't find anything. First I was using AWS SQS  and due to its maximum 50 connection limitation and finally decided to settle with Redis + Laravel Horizon and auto scaling based on CPU usage.